# Spring boot XmlBeanDefinitionReader not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating maven multi module having two sub modules. One is simple DAO layer which has databse repositories and other is spring boot app which is command line app. I am using mongodb and spring-data-monodb for database. When I configure mongodb using xml config as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" 
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoClient" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" 
    credentials="username:password@source" replica-set="server1uri:27017,server2uri:27017,server3uri:27017" >
        <mongo:client-options connections-per-host="50" threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="5000" ssl="true" />
    </mongo:mongo-client>

</beans>
```

It is working fine. I've defined this file in dao module and used in spring boot module using @ImportResource on SpringBootApplication and it is working fine.

Now I need to provide this file as command line argument when running spring boot jar (java -jar app.jar /path/to/bean.xml). What I did, I implemented CommandLineRunner in SpringBootApplication and in that method loaded above xml file using XmlBeanDefinitionReader.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Provide path for mongodb connection file");
            return;
        }

        XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlBeanDefinitionReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(applicationContext);

        Resource beanFile = new FileSystemResource(args[0]);
        xmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(beanFile);

        // Rest of logic.
    }
}
```

Then it is not properly able to cast mongo credentials. It throws below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential' for property 'credentials[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Somehow it is not able to convert credentials. I am using spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

CommandLineRunner is too late to register the bean definition in spring, so we need to implement the **BeanFactoryPostProcessor** to load bean definition xml, i didn't fully test the following code, you can do it and give me feedback

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoCredentialPropertyEditor;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    private static String xmlFile;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Provide path for mongodb connection file");
            return;
        }
        xmlFile = args[0];
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
        if (configurableListableBeanFactory instanceof BeanDefinitionRegistry) {
            XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlBeanDefinitionReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader((BeanDefinitionRegistry)configurableListableBeanFactory);

            Resource beanFile = new FileSystemResource(Application.xmlFile);
            xmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(beanFile);
           try {
            configurableListableBeanFactory.registerCustomEditor(Class.forName("[Lcom.mongodb.MongoCredential;"), MongoCredentialPropertyEditor.class);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I will test and give feedback. Thanks

Comment: i give you a workaround of this issue, please test it again

Answer (score 0):

you should implement the **BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor**, so the bean registration is as early as possible

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    private static String xmlFile;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Provide path for mongodb connection file");
            return;
        }
        xmlFile = args[0];
        SpringApplication.run(MongoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
            XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlBeanDefinitionReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(registry);
            Resource beanFile = new FileSystemResource(Application.xmlFile);
            xmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(beanFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this answer is better than the above one

Comment: Thanks. I will try again and inform you.

Comment: @MaheshBhuva any progress about this question?

Comment: i indeed fix this issue, so there may be other problems, if you can create a demo project in github, i think i can help your more

Comment: Sure, I will upload it whenever I get time and will inform you. Thanks for help.